# The discrete topological space is locally connected but not connected

Tags: general-topology

$\tau_d$ is the discrete topology.

$(X,\tau_d)$ is not connected because if it has $\{x,y\}\subset X$, then we have $A=\{x\}$ and $B= X \setminus\{x\}$ such as $A \cup B= X$ and $A \cap B = \emptyset$.

But... why is it locally connected?

Comment: Single points are connected. Discrete topology means single points are open.

Comment: If your topology is the discrete topology, the adjective 'locally' becomes almost meaningless.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because every $x\in X$ has a connected neighbourhood: $\{x\}$.